# Where should I put the actual computation functions in my MVC Java project?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, design-patterns, controller, dao

I have simple java project with separated DAO classes, Controllers and Models.

First of all, who should care/use DAO instances? I have DAO interfaces and classes that manage queries to DB, but the actual instances of this DAO classes should be in Controllers or Models?

Then, the actual computation of what the controller receives from the View, where should I manage it? Should I pass all the inputs to the model and create a method that manages and calculate the result and then return it to the controller? Or the controller should have this method?

I don't find clear answers on the internet regarding this aspect of MVC.